# parse escaped HTML into node in xqilla

Tags: xquery, xqilla

I'm trying to get text from an rss 2.0 feed (description tag) using XQilla. The address is [here](http://idnes.cz.feedsportal.com/c/34387/f/625936/index.rss). This is fine but the tag contains escaped HTML like

```
"&lt;a href="some_address&gt;..."
```

It would be useful to have this HTML in a node and further work with it, but I am at a loss here. I can get the tag contents with

```
let $desc := $item/*[name()='description']
```

but do not know how to unescape it. I tried parse-html, which only strips the text of tags and returns a string, like the data() function. Searching on the web suggests that extension functions exist for this, but in other parsers. Is there a way to do it in XQilla? By the way, the code I am working on is a JAWS ResearchIt lookup source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQilla has – like lots of other XQuery implementations – a [proprietary function to load XML and HTML from a string](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/ExtensionFunctions) (they don't have anchor tags, thus you need to scroll through the document, I'm sorry).

```
xqilla:parse-xml($xml as xs:string?) as document-node()?
xqilla:parse-html($html as xs:string?) as document-node()?
```

Given `$desc` contains the unparsed HTML, `xqilla:parse-html($desc)` will return the parse result.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply, I found my old question via google and I have a similar problem now. The xqilla parse functions are not exactly what I want since they create document-node, I want node()*, for example a sequence of paragraphs with images, but creating a document for each node and getting only the children works. I am not sure about performance but it is sufficient for my purposes

Comment: Can't help you with that. Anyway: this should be asked as another, new question (as it is).